# OnPlatform Conditional in .NET MAUI FlyoutItem Items Colleciton

Tags: maui

In .NET MAUI, how do I use the OnPlatform element to conditionally include a ShellContent item in a FlyoutItem Items collection?
This Xaml will not compile (namespaces removed for clarity)

```
<Shell>
   <FlyoutItem>
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Items">
          <On Platform="iOS">
              <ShellContent
                Title="Map"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MapPage}"
                Route="MapPage" />              
          </On>
          <On Platform="Android">
              <ShellContent
                Title="Map"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:AMapPage}"
                Route="MapPage" />              
          </On>
       </OnPlatform>
```

Comment: *"will not compile"* - what is the error message?  And on which line and column? `Andoroid` is a typo when you put code in question, not in your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property `IsVisible` for `ShellContent` , you can use bind to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell 
{

    public bool isVisible_Android { get; set; }

    public bool isVisible_iOS { get; set; }

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS )
        {
            isVisible_iOS = true;
        }
        else if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
        {
            isVisible_Android = true;
        }
        

        BindingContext = this;
    }

}
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" > 

    <ShellContent  Title="Map"  Route="MapPage"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MapPage}" IsVisible="{Binding isVisible_iOS}" />

    <ShellContent  Title="Map"  Route="AMapPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AMapPage}" IsVisible="{Binding isVisible_Android}"/>

</FlyoutItem>
```